# UIView touchesCancelled Not Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, touch

I have a subclassed `UIView` that is not receiving `touchesCancelled`.  If a touch comes down and drags outside the screen (or any other instances where `touchesCancelled` should be called), `touchesEnded` is called instead of `touchesCancelled`. It is never called!

I got:

```
self.clipsToBounds = true
self.isExclusiveTouch = true
self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
```

Other sibling views seems to get their `touchesCancelled` called.  Also I have no gesture recognizers attached.

Comment: Please show actual code, not a tiny excerpt with a few properties, and explain how to do "a touch comes down and drags outside the screen" and what you expect. There isn't even any `touchesCancelled` in the code you've shown! That's no way to ask this question. Prove an MCVE please.

Answer (score 3):

From Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621116-touchescancelled ...

> UIKit calls this method when it receives a system interruption requiring cancellation of the touch sequence. An interruption is anything that causes the application to become inactive or causes the view handling the touch events to be removed from its window.

So `touchesCancelled` does *not* get called when the touch moves/drags outside the view.

Comment: I apologize, I had to correct the OP, I meant 'outside the screen'.  Also any other occurrences where `touchesCancelled` would be called in other views.

Comment: That's still not a "system interruption" - you are getting `touchesEnded` by design.